# Communicate interactive Shell Via PHP

Tags: php, console-application

Supposed to Open SHELL App (C) which i Coded as interface for my purpose
I Already know about `exec` and `shel_exec` which couldn't be helpful on this.

My Console Application which i had to OPEN on php is interactive shell and batch (Both Modes are available).

I Need to communicate to shell, not just opening and get result (like exec func).
I want to Open My Shell and Send commands to it , which can be Interactive I/O or batch I/O.

Comment: Why don't you leave it listening, then connect to it via sockets?

Comment: Are you asking how to make it interactive? If so then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929629/how-do-i-write-a-command-line-interactive-php-script

Comment: It could be a temp solution but im looking for permanent solution because many console applications has this behavior and i cant customize all of them

Comment: Consider SQLite3 Command Line tool , it works same . You need to communicate with Command Line shell

Comment: There is [`ssh2_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) that is part of the SSH2 extension for PHP. That could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well If No Straight solution found with php built in Function I am going to pass my command as String Parameter to console application

But Straight solutions with php built in library and behavior still would be accepted